# Query plan changes from efficient view filter pushdown to very slow HashJoin when joining with a trigger Transition table

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to exploit view filter pushdown to incrementally maintain a "stat" table based on which attributes of a product are "filled" (not empty strings or arrays).
You can have access to the whole source code here:

- context: https://github.com/docteurklein/pgpim/blob/main/src/schema.sql
- the relevant lines: https://github.com/docteurklein/pgpim/blob/7c7b61ade38c23d42c27ea7537746e2fb5c851e4/src/schema/product_completeness.sql#L75-L76

And I successfully reproduced a minimal example:

```sql
create table pv (
  p int not null,
  a text not null,
  v jsonb not null,
  primary key (p, a)
);

create view ps as
  select p,
  count(v) filter (where v not in (to_jsonb(text '')))
  from pv
  group by 1
;

insert into pv 
select i, 'a1', to_jsonb(text '1a1')
from generate_series(1, 100000) i;

explain (analyze) with change_set (p, a, v) as (
  values
  (1, 'a1', to_jsonb(text 'first'))
-- , (2, 'a2', to_jsonb(text 'second')) -- uncomment = 2 ROWS = VERY BAD
)
select distinct ps.*
from change_set pv
join ps using (p);
```

online version here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uxBVadPXUhte6kbTDcv5pJ/0.
Click "Run" and see the plans and execution times differ **a lot** (from .5ms to 8s!), just based on the number of rows I'm joining the view with.

I'm using a `values` CTE here to simulate a transition table of an after-update trigger (represented as a `NamedTupleStore` IRL), but the results are the same than with a transition table **as soon as the CTE yields more than 1 row**.

BTW, The transition table join is slow even if it contains 1 row.

Here are the plans of the real payloads:

- 1 row: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/40fe81ae8bf3hhdg
- 2 rows (or transition table): https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/69d6gegh7gh4823f

I hope the links provided will be helpful and provide enough info to debug, but I'll happily edit the question with more details!

Do you have any idea why, and how I could fix this problem?

Thanks for taking the time to read me :)

EDIT: I got an even more minimal example:

```sql
explain analyze with cs(i) as (
 values 
 (1)
--,(2)
)
select * from cs 
join (select i from generate_series(1, 10000000) i) v1
  using (i);
```

The plan differs considerably depending on the CTE containing 1 or 2 rows.